# Load XML data to array

Tags: c#, xml, arrays, xml-serialization

I might have a simple question but I just can't figure it out.
First I've saved data to a XML file, using this [Source](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/XMLArrays.aspx).
First class:

```
public class Employees
{

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Employees() { }

    public Employees(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

}

public class group
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Employees> Employees { get; set; }

    public group()
    {
        Employees = new List<Employees>();
    }
```

Saving XML data in another class.

```
 public class SaveXML
{
    static public void SaveData(group info)
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(info.GetType());

        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("dataArray.xml");
        xs.Serialize(writer, info);
        writer.Close();


    }
}
```

Form1:

```
    private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] employees = new string[EmployList.Items.Count];
        for (int x = 0; x < EmployList.Items.Count; x++)
        {
            employees[x] = EmployList.Items[x].ToString();
        }

        try
        {
            group groups = new group();

            groups.Name = GroupText.Text;
            for (int x = 0; x < employees.Length; x++)
            {
                groups.Employees.Add(new Employees(employees[x]));
            }

            SaveXML.SaveData(groups);
        }
        catch (Exception es)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(es.Message);
        }

    }
```

Now I want to load this data into a array,
Here is my class for loading data:

```
public class LoadXML
{
    static public void LoadData(group LoadInfo)
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(LoadInfo.GetType());
        TextReader Read = new StreamReader("dataxml.xml");
        List<Employees> GroupList;
        GroupList = (List<Employees>)xs.Deserialize(Read);
    }
}
```

This is what I've tried, but it gives me errors:

```
    private void LoadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        group groups = new group();
        LoadXML Loading = new LoadXML();
        Loading.LoadData(groups);
        string[] array = new string[10];
        array = groups.Employees.ToArray; //error line

    }
```

So now my question is how to get the GroupList into a Array in the main function.
I want to have it in a array because I think it's easier to get a single name out of a array, but on the other hand, the length of the array depends on user input.

This is a test program, not the actual program I'm using, this is just to learn it and then implement it in my original project.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I think you have some confusion at the load method. You are creating GroupList object, but you arent returning in. Put return statement at the end and change void to List<Employees>

Answer (score 0):

If GroupList is List or it contains property which has employees in a list. You can just call a GroupList.ToArray(), or groups.Employees.ToArray() if you have a variable called groups.

Comment: Thought the same thing but didnt work:
will edit post what I tried with a LoadButton

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LoadXML
{
    static public void LoadData(group LoadInfo)
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(LoadInfo.GetType());
        TextReader Read = new StreamReader("dataxml.xml");
        List<Employees> GroupList;
        GroupList = (List<Employees>)xs.Deserialize(Read);

       // Now you have an array of Employees - but why do you need it. you have already a list class. it's verymuch flexible to implement a List class

        Employee [] employeeArray = GroupList.ToArray();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `LINQ` for selecting name or whatever you want. It's very simple

```
List<Employees> GroupList;
GroupList = (List<Employees>)xs.Deserialize(Read);

...
String name = GroupList.Where( x => x.Name == "WhatName").Select(x => x.Name)
```

**[Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know way directly fill data from XML to array but you can read data from xml file using DATASET object

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml("Path for xml file");
        int[] arr=new arr[ds.rows.count-1];
        int i=0;
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            arr[i]=dr["Field Name in xml file"].ToString();
            i++;
        }
```